# Entity framework.. self referencing table.. get records of Depth =x?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, self-reference

I am successfully using a self referencing table in entity framework.
But I can't figure out how to get the records of the desired depth ?

What should be the logic for this ?

---

Model :

```
public class FamilyLabel
{
    public FamilyLabel()
    {
        this.Children = new Collection<FamilyLabel>();
        this.Families = new Collection<Family>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FamilyLabelId { get; set; }
    public string FamilyLabelName { get; set; }

    public virtual FamilyLabel Parent { get; set; }

    public int JamaatId { get; set; }
    public virtual Jamaat Jamaat { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Family> Families { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FamilyLabel>  Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confused. If you are working in C# you have objects, not tables.

Comment: @DaleM - both title and tags refer to EF

Comment: @DaleM Why is it confusing ? I am simply asking that I need to know the depth of a record..

Comment: Maybe you can show code how you populate a hierarchy of your objects, because I think there is the answer to your question.

Comment: @GertArnold I posted the model code.
It has two helpful properties right now ... i.e. "parent" & "Children". Can we create a function , which given a LabelId, return's its depth ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically you can create a method that builds query expression dynamically based on the specified depth level:

```
context.FamilyLabels.Where(x => 
    x.Parent. ... .Parent != null &&
    x.Parent.Parent ... .Parent == null);
```

The following implementation does the trick:

```
public static IList<FamilyLabel> Get(DbConnection connection, int depth)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FamilyLabel));
    Expression current = p;

    for (int i = 0; i < deep; i++)
    {
        current = Expression.Property(current, "Parent");
    }

    var nullConst = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(FamilyLabel));

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<FamilyLabel, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.NotEqual(current, nullConst),
            Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(current, "Parent"), nullConst)), p);

    using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext(connection))
    {
        return context.FamilyLabels.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
}
```

However, presumably this will create a bunch of join expressions, so maybe this is not the most optimal way.

Comment: Does this get translated to T-SQL?